# CSS Condition for Scroll To Top Button based on Page height

Tags: css, height

I have a scroll to top jquery button that will scroll to top of page when clicked. I'd like to show this button only when scrolling is needed.

For example: if page/content height (not window height) is more than 980px, show the button. if less, hide the button.

How do i do this using pure css? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if you can do this using pure CSS. You can use media query to achieve this if it depends on window height. You can use something like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-height: 980px){
    #your-button-id{
        display:none;
    }
}
```

If you want it to depend on your content's height you can use Javascript. The example I am giving your is in jQuery but you can do it without jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ // To make sure the DOM is loaded before you get the body's height
    if( $('body').height() < 980 )
        $('#your-button-id').css('display', 'none');
    else
        $('#your-button-id').css('display', 'block');

    $(window).resize(function(){ // To make sure that when window is resized, if you have media querys that modify the css and probably the body's height, you still hide the button if the height is no more than 980px
        if( $('body').height() < 980 )
            $('#your-button-id').css('display', 'none');
        else
            $('#your-button-id').css('display', 'block');
    }
}
```

UPDATE: You can show the button whenever the page content's height is greater than your window height. In this case the condition would be

```
if( $('body').height() <= $(window).height() )
```

Comment: If this require JS then a better requirement would be: if content height > window height show button. if not, hide.

Comment: Yes it is, I was just basing my answer in the requirement you gave of 980px

Comment: So, is this the solution to your question?

Comment: I have a css applied to the content wrapper div to be height: 100% and footer absolute position, bottom zero. So this wont work. But thank you very much anyway for your help.

Comment: Give me some example code of your problem and I will gladly help you out.